# How do I get the terms aligned after linebreak?

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

I am typesetting the following equation in multline environment. The terms following the linebreaks align  after some spacing which are unintended. how does one align all the terms to left?

```
P(r)= \frac{9\sqrt{3}}{4\pi(1-\alpha^2)}\frac{r(1+r)}{(1+r+r^2)^2}\left[\frac{2\alpha(9+(11+20r(1 + r))\alpha^2)}{(3 +(1 + 2 r)^2 \alpha^2)^2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}\arccot\left(2\alpha\sqrt{\frac{1 + r + r^2}{3(1-\alpha^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{(1 + r + r^2)(1 - \alpha^2)}}\\+ \frac{18 r^3 \alpha + 2 r (20 + r (20 + 11 r)) \alpha^3}{(3 r^2 + (2 + r)^2 \alpha^2)^2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}\arccot\left(\frac{2\alpha}{r}\sqrt{\frac{1 + r + r^2}{3(1-\alpha^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{(1 + r + r^2)(1 - \alpha^2)}}\\-\frac{18 (1 + r)^3 \alpha + 2 (1 + r) (11 + r (2 + 11 r)) \alpha^3}{(3 (1 + r)^2 + (1 - r)^2 \alpha^2)^2}- \frac{\sqrt{3}\arccot\left(\frac{2\alpha}{1+r}\sqrt{\frac{1 + r + r^2}{3(1-\alpha^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{(1 + r + r^2)(1 - \alpha^2)}}\right]
```

Comment: please make it easier for people to help you by making your example something that people can run to see the issue. you tagged it as tex-core, but it's clearly intended to be latex, and your text says it's in multline, but your example doesn't show that environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three observations:

- Your code is missing both a `\right.` directive at the end of the first row and a `\left.` directive at the beginning of the third row.
- The three instances of `{3(1-\alpha^2}` should be `{3(1-\alpha^2)}`, right?
- If don't want the second and third rows to be progressively more indented relative to the first, don't use a `multline` environment. Instead, use either an `align` environment (which requires two `\notag` directives) or a nested pair of `equation` and `aligned` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page block parameters appropriately
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot} 
\begin{document} 

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b] % 'b' option to place equation number on last row
P(r)&= \frac{9\sqrt{3}}{4\pi(1-\alpha^2)} 
      \frac{r(1+r)}{(1+r+r^2)^2} 
      \left[ \frac{2\alpha(9+(11+20r(1+r))\alpha^2)}
         {(3 +(1 + 2 r)^2 \alpha^2)^2} 
      + \frac{\sqrt{3}\arccot\left(2\alpha \sqrt{\frac{1 + r + r^2}
      {3(1-\alpha^2)}}\,\right)}{
      \sqrt{(1 + r + r^2)(1 - \alpha^2)}} \right. \\ % end of first row
&\quad+\frac{18 r^3 \alpha + 2 r (20 + r (20 + 11 r)) \alpha^3}
      {(3 r^2 + (2 + r)^2 \alpha^2)^2}
      +\frac{\sqrt{3}\arccot\left(\frac{2\alpha}{r}
      \sqrt{\frac{1 + r + r^2}{3(1-\alpha^2)}}\,\right)}
      {\sqrt{(1 + r + r^2)(1 - \alpha^2)}} \\ % end of second row
&\quad-\left.\frac{18 (1+r)^3 \alpha + 2 (1+r) (11 + r (2 + 11 r)) \alpha^3}
      {(3 (1+r)^2 + (1 - r)^2 \alpha^2)^2}
      - \frac{\sqrt{3}\arccot\left(\frac{2\alpha}{1+r} 
      \sqrt{\frac{1 + r + r^2}{3(1-\alpha^2)}}\,\right)}
      {\sqrt{(1 + r + r^2)(1 - \alpha^2)}}\right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `align`? Not `split`? By the way, the symbol for the arcsine is “arcsin” with no space, so it should be the same for the arccotangent.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for this. I'll fix the "arccot" rendering right away. On the placement of the equation number (and the use of `align` vs. `split`): The OP stated that he/she started out with a `multline` environment; since `multline` places the equation number on the final line, I chose to keep that particular setting, going for the `align` solution with two `\notag` directives. Maybe the OP will weight in and express his/her preferences?

Comment: Then `aligned` with `[b]` option. But I still think `split` is preferable.

Comment: @egreg - I've implemented your first suggestion. Let's see if the OP comes back with an indication of preference for where the equation number ought to go.

Comment: Hi. I replaced multline with align (not aligned) and it worked well. Thanks for the answers. @Mico